# How to find content of a specific cell with row and column index?

Tags: javascript

Using the coordinates of cell i want to find the content of a specific cell.. I mean if we have row index and column index of a specific cell and we want to get the content of that specific cell by passing the index of cell as arguments in a function and then searching for the content of that specific cell in the html table.

```
function createtable() {
  function displaytable(argument) {
    var tr=document.createElement('tr');
    for (var i=0; i < argument.length; i++) {
      var td=document.createElement('td');
      if (i == 0) {
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(argument[i]));
      }
      if (i == 1) {
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(argument[i]));
      }
      if (i == 3) {
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(argument[i]));
      }
      if (i == 2) {
        td.ondblclick= function () {
        var column_index= (this.cellIndex) -1;
        var row_index= (this.parentNode.rowIndex);
        search_cell(row_index,column_index);
      }
      td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(argument[i]));
    }
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
   document.getElementById('table_body').appendChild(tr);
 }
 document.write("<table border=\"1\"><tr><th>INDEX</th><th>--CELL NAME--</th><th>--PIN NAME--</th><th>--PG PIN--</th></tr><tbody id='table_body'></tbody></table>");

 for (var x=0; x < array_cells.length; x++) {
   displaytable([x+1,array_cells[x].cell,array_cells[x].pins,array_cells[x].pg_pins])
 }
 function search_cell(row_index,column_index) {
   //What to write over here
 }
}
```

Comment: Till now i have just created a table dynamically using data from an json array. now i want that when i click on data/content of a cell of table i created using javascript i get back that data in a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an event listener to your table and then get the event's target innerHTML like this:

```
yourTable.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    console.log(event.target.innerHTML);
});
```

You don't need to add a listeners to each cell this is a waste of resources, use one global listener for the table.

Comment: yourTable is the object that contains the html table element, for example:

    yourTable = document.createElement('table');
    // After, you add some elements in it
    // Finally, add the listener to the table element

Comment: Where in my code i have make changes to apply this.. i tried differnt ways nothing is working can you where should i apply this change..? In my code object will be my table id??

Comment: Do not use document.write() to add new elements, use instead document.createElement (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement), but you still can use document.getElementById('table_body').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    console.log(event.target.innerHTML);
});

Comment: if you will indent your code correctly you'll find easily errors in it (read this: http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html), and use a debugger like Firebug, share your code using jsfiddle

Comment: you lost some brackets in the code, write your code according to the js code convension described in the link that I provided you, it will help you to see these syntax mistakes, use a debugger ! and share your code in jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) !!!

Comment: Its working now...thanx for so much help... but if i want to get the row and column number of cell of table..what i have to do..?? i mean the cell on which i will click in the table i want to get the row and column number of that cell..

Comment: give them some names like "00", "01", "02", "10", "11", "12" ... and inside the listener: console.log(event.target.name); You will have two numbers, the first one is the row index, the second one is the cell index.

Comment: Can i also use the row and column value to find the specific cell in a table...?? I mean if i have the row and column coordinates of a cell and i want to find the content of that cell...is it possible..? if yes then tell me how..

Comment: if you gave them names, I mean you set the "name" attribute as I said then you can select them by using document.getElementsByName('theName')[0];

Comment: In my function search_cell what should i write to get the content of cell..?? i have coordinates of cell as arguments of function as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Markup:

```
<td onclick="click(event)">content</td>
```

JS:

```
function click(event)
{
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    var content = target.innerHTML || target.textContent;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NRKsT/

Comment: What does || means in it? The content variable will have the data/content of html table cell?

Comment: This is for browser compatibility. Typically double pipe ("||") means logical OR. In this context, it is behaving as a null coalesce.

Comment: Please can you elaborate or provide some refernce where i can get more discription about null coalesce?

Comment: @sam1989. A null coalesce is an expression that returns the first value that is NOT NULL. .innerHTML isn't supported in all browsers not is .textContent. Using a null coalesce allows us to function in all browsers with very little effort. http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/10/14/JavaScript-Gem-Null-Coalescing-using-the-OR-Operator.aspx

Comment: @sam1989 You can do this really easily with jQuery using the [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method. Consider raising a new question if you can't figure this one out.

Comment: @sam1989. You should raise a new question for that. Note also that it will take 10-20 lines in JS or one line in jQuery, but if it's a learning exercise then that's fine.

Comment: You can. jQuery is a framework build on JS. It makes the common/difficult JS tasks significantly easier.

Comment: @sam1989. Raise a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose this is your HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
        <td>Cell 5</td>
        <td>Cell 6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This jQuery code will do what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('td').click(function() {
       somevar = this.innerHTML;
       alert( this.innerHTML );
    });
});
```

If you prefer simple JavaScript, then:

```
var temp = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for( var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++ ) {
    temp[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
       alert( this.innerHTML );
    });
}
```

Comment: instead of `alert( this.innerHTML );` use `var temp = this.innerHTML; someMethod( temp );` assuming someMethod is the name of the method you want to call and pass parameters.

Comment: Can we also get the value of adjacent cell without clicking over it? I mean if i click can it be possible i get both content of cell...one of row1column1 and row1column2 together in same variable?

Comment: That would be a separate question. If my answer helped you mark it as the correct answer. A post a new question

Comment: Maybe that is because you have not voted on answers for most of the questions and have not marked them as answered. Read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

if you're constructing this table in javascript, the simplest thing is to add an onclick method to the cell in which you return this.innerHTML

```
var e = document.createElement('td');
e.onClick = function(){
   doSomeThingWith( this.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: I want to make each cell of table to return its data when i click over them? Will it be same for every cell...

Comment: each cell will think of itself as `this`, so yes, you'll get each cell's contents.

Comment: Can we also get the value of adjacent cell without clicking over it? I mean if i click on cell like row1cell2 can it be possible i get both content of cell...one of row1column1 and row1column2 together in same variable?

Comment: that's a little more tricky as you'd have to climb the DOM tree up to the row and then find the adjacent cell.  In that case, I'd recommend giving your cell IDs ("cell_1", "cell_2") and then when you click on a cell get the number of the clicked cell and figure out what the other number should be and then use getElementById to fetch it.